# How to set timeout for webBrowser navigate event

Tags: c#, timeout, browser, set, navigatetourl

how can i set timeout for webBrowser navigate (url) event

c# netframework 4.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By using a Timer of course.  For example:

```
    public void NavigateTo(Uri url) {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Timeout on navigation");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Url == webBrowser1.Url && timer1.Enabled) {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            // etc..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't that wait for the WebBrowser to actually complete navigation before cancelling, rather than ending it after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Erm, no.  There's nothing to end.  Just navigate elsewhere.

Comment: so when timer ticked i will navigate somewhere else ?

Comment: and i will register this event like this righ ?    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

Comment: When the timer ticks then you got a timeout.  Not sure what you want to do after that.  Sure, navigate somewhere else.

Comment: i want to end previous navigation event. how can i do this without navigating somewhere else ?

Comment: webBrowser1.DocumentText = "Canceled"; will do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using following approach based on `Navigating` and `Navigated` events. The time between these two events are observed for redirecting to home pgae.

```
        //Navigation Timer
        timer2.Enabled = true;
        timer2.Interval = 30000;

        br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
        br.DocumentCompleted += writeToTextBoxEvent;
        br.Navigating += OnNavigating;
        br.Navigated  += OnNavigated;

        br.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        br.Navigate(ConfigValues.websiteUrl);

    private void OnNavigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        //Reset Timer
        timer2.Stop();
        timer2.Start();

        WriteLogFunction("OnNavigating||||||"+e.Url.ToString());
    }

    private void OnNavigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Stop Timer
        timer2.Stop();

        WriteLogFunction("NAVIGATED <><><><><><><> " + e.Url.ToString());
    }


    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WriteLogFunction(" Navigation Timeout TICK");
        br.Stop();
        br.Navigate(ConfigValues.websiteUrl);
    }
```

**Reference**

1. [Create a time-out for webbrowser loading method](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0ef0dd1-15e9-4ae9-a53e-c25601b32147/create-a-timeout-for-webbrowser-loading-method?forum=vblanguage)
2. [webbrowser timeout if page wont load](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e682b71e-a741-4d9d-95d5-f9e977d11c03/looking-for-webbrowser-timeout-if-page-wont-load?forum=vbgeneral)

Comment: So does `br.Stop()` cause the web browser control to stop trying to navigate?